# Proxy websocket wss:// to ws:// apache

Tags: apache, websocket, wss, proxypass

I couldn't connect my websocket using `wss://`.

I found that there is a way to use Apache to expose

- `wss://domain.com` - frontend (Apache)
- `ws://domain.com:9090` - backend plaintext

My configuration:

```
ProxyPass        /websocket ws://domain.com:9090
ProxyPassReverse /websocket ws://domain.com:9090
```

This code in apache config will send request from any address ended with `/websocket` to `ws://domain.com:9090`
ex: `ws://websocket` will be `ws://domain.com:9090`

I want to do it for `wss://` also. Example: `wss://websocket` must point to `ws://domain.com:9090`.

It doesn't work and I get this error in browser console:

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is there any mistake here? Thanks you.

Answer (score 22):

i worked 24 hours for find this and searched a lot of forum but no one write about success.
here is my server configuration :

> CentOS release 6.7 ,  Apache 4.2.18

here is what i did finally :
first i found that modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so must be enable in apache config file , but my apache didn't have that module and after a lot of search i found that module is Available in apache 2.4.5 and later.

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

i downloaded https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.18.tar.gz
extracted  httpd-2.4.18\modules\proxy\mod_proxy_wstunnel.c and uploaded to my server root
then from terminal could compile it again with these commonds :

```
chmod 755 mod_proxy_wstunnel.c #set permission
pxs -i -a -c mod_proxy_tunnel.c #compile module
```

pxs command did compile the module and wrote in apache config file to load it

```
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

after that i added these lines to end of apache config file :

```
RewriteEngine on
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /myws ws://mysite.com:8091
ProxyPassReverse /myws ws://mysite.com:8091
```

AND NOW : it works !
in client side js  you can set ws url like this :

```
var protocol = 'ws://'; 
if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
            protocol = 'wss://';
   }

 var wsUri =protocol+ "mysite.com/myws";  

 var ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

and it will forward request to ws://mysite.com:8091
doesnt matter the page loaded with https or http , it will direct all request ended with /myws to ws://mysite.com:8091

Comment: I am trying to configure a proxy to catch wss requests and redirect it throw ws to my Server for Dev environnment needs.
I don't really understand what you did.

I already activated mod_proxy and mod_proxy_tunnel (I am on apache2 2.4.10). Now i have to change my apache config (I tried in .htaccess). It Doesn't works, I have an 500 internal server error. And i don't really understand the lines : ProxyPass /myws ws://mysite.com:8091 ProxyPassReverse /myws ws://mysite.com:8091

For you, what is mysite.com? the address of the websocket serveur?

Answer (score 21):

You need to enable some Apache2 modules:

```
$ a2enmod proxy proxy_wstunnel proxy_http rewrite
```

Then you can use this configuration to solve your problem.

```
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyVia on      
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://example.com:9090/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass               /websocket http://example.com:9090/websocket
    ProxyPassReverse        /websocket http://example.com:9090/websocket
```

Apache2 automatically upgrades the connection to websocket with ws://, you don't need to set the ws:// manually. I tried dozens of configurations and this is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: oh my GOD thank you so much for that. I've searched high and low, this one did the trick.

Comment: So finally after 5 days, My Hackathon to find right answer is ended. I must create a video tutorial for this bug. and how to get over it. Thanks @florian

Comment: Was working for me too after almost an hour of trial and error.
 Added it to the docs and backlinked to here.
https://github.com/Koenkk/zigbee2mqtt.io/pull/1924

Answer (score 5):

the problem I was trying to solve was similar to this one. I have a reverse proxy running under Apache 2.4 on CentOs 7 which has to work with both https and wss requests.

Behind the reverse proxy I have my app server running on an internal network. the virtual host configuration in the /etc/httpd/httpd.conf config file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   RewriteCond %(HTTP:Upgrade) websocket [NC]   # Required to handle the websocket connection
   RewriteCond %(HTTP:Connection) upgrade [NC]
   RewriteRule /(.*) ws://192.160.0.1/$1 [P,L]

  SSLEngine on # SSL Certificates handling
  SSLCertificateFile ssl/cert.pem # Public Certificate
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/key.pem # Private certificate
  SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/ca.pem # CA or chain certificate

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /websocket ws://192.168.0.1 # First you need to write the specific rules
 ProxyPassReverse /websocket ws://102.168.0.1
 ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.1 # Then the generic rules for the proxy.
 ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.1
 </VirtualHost>
```

In your case, you will have to replace the ServerName, the SSL certificates location, and the destination of the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

wss needs following module
Uncomment line at the  httpd.conf of apache conf
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

Answer (score 0):

The /websocket path is missing in your ProxyPass configuration path.

Use:

```
ProxyPass /websocket ws://example.com:9090/websocket
ProxyPassReverse /websocket ws://example.com:9090/websocket
```

Additional information:
Like others mentioned, you have to uncomment the line:

> LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

If you are also using a http ProxyPass thats relative path is "/" (forwarding everything directly), the specific "/websocket" path configuration must be configured first, otherwise "/" grabs first.

```
ProxyPass /websocket ws://example.com:9090/websocket
ProxyPassReverse /websocket ws://example.com:9090/websocket

ProxyPass balancer://ac-cluster/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:9090
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it for aria 2. I just enabled some modules and added a  single line to config. (env: debian buster/apache 2.4).
enabling modes:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_balancer proxy_wstunnel proxy_http
```

and add this line to ssl site config file inside the virtual host directive :

```
ProxyPass /jsonrpc ws://127.0.0.1:6888/jsonrpc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach using the `<Location>` blocks to have shorter configurations and more readable.

If you want a frontend webserver with HTTPs support (with Apache HTTPd) to proxy request to an underlying backend webserver in plaintext, here a possibility:

```
#
# https://example.com/websocket   -> [Apache:443] -> Websocket plaintext -> [Backend websocket:9000]
# https://example.com/other-stuff -> [Apache:443] -> HTTP      plaintext -> [Backend webserver:8080]
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # My application without websocket (if you have that)
    <Location />
        # This can be a Docker container, PHP-FPM, Tomcat, etc.
        ProxyPass        http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>

    # Plaintext websockets handled by their dedicated path
    <Location /websocket>
        ProxyPass ws://localhost:9090/
    </Location>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      ssl/cert.pem # Public Certificate
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   ssl/key.pem  # Private certificate
    SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/ca.pem   # CA or chain certificate

</VirtualHost>
```

The example also tried to show how to integrate your HTTP web application with your websocket, since that is a frequent issue.

### How and Why it works

Here some reference from official documentation:

> When used inside a  section, the first argument is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the .
>
> ― https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass

Also note that very probably you do not need any `ProxyPassReverse` in the websocket location since in theory it does not have sense there.

Also note that usually you just need to write `ProxyPass ws://localhost:9090/` and not `ProxyPass ws://localhost:9090/websocket` or something, since the backend websocket server usually has no location.

This answer was useful at least in Apache/2.4.6 but probably in other versions.

### Troubleshooting

If it does not work, search the errors logs of your Apache HTTPd webserver. This really deserves a dedicated research and cannot be clarified here.

Try to isolate the problem to see if you have a problem with proxies in general, or just with websocket.

Answer (score -2):

I want to share this in case it helps somebody else avoid days of wasted time and effort.

I was giving up after researching everything. I was ready to start following the code of the different proxy modules, yes I know, a spiderweb..., but I was desperate. As a last resource I installed wireshark to follow exactly what was going on in my network. After installing wireshark, the instructions asked me to restart my server through a power off/on cycle. So, I did. When I started tracing it, to my complete surprise, the server was proxying perfectly the wss requests to ws, no problems! So I had the correct setup to start with but something got messed up in Ubuntu 20.4 / Apache 2.4.41 / node 14.17.2 that required a complete restart of the machine where the server operates. Crazy! But that was it...